# How do I center text in a spinner in Android

Tags: android

I have a Spinner in my LinearLayour.

I am trying to center text in spinner:

[image]

This is my XML for that element:

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/project_Spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:padding="1dip"


    android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
/>
```

the declaration of the spinner in the Activity:

```
// Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, NomProjets);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Thanks,

Comment: try android:gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: add android:gravity="center" to your Spinner element

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The component that actually creates the items for the `Spinner` is the adapter. So you should customize it (by overriding the `getView()` method) to return centered `TextView` widgets.

In your case, replace the `new ArrayAdapter<String> ...` initialization with this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, NomProjets)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return setCentered(super.getView(position, convertView, parent));
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return setCentered(super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent));
    }

    private View setCentered(View view)
    {
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        return view;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Matiash's answer works. Here is another way:

Actually the text in the spinner is wrapped in a TextView , so we can override the android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item.xml(which is located at sdk\platforms\android-xx\data\res\layout) , create an new xml in the /layout folder, adding an attribute:
android:gravity="center" to make the text in the TextView center.

[such like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8DsT.png)