# How to center simple_spinner_dropdown_item in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, spinner

I want to **center** the text of my **simple_spinner_dropdown_item** element, so I got this solution:

```
private void addCountriesToSpinner(){
    DatabaseHelper dhHelp = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    _countryNames = dhHelp.getAllCountryNames();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, _countryNames){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            return setCentered(super.getView(position, convertView, parent));
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            return setCentered(super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent));
        }

        private View setCentered(View view){
            TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setTextSize(18);
            return view;
        }
    };
```

However, this is just working for the **simple_spinner_item** where all the dropdown items are way to tight. But when ever I replace it by **simple_spinner_dropdown_item** the centering is no longer working.

I guess the answer lies in this line, but I dont know how to adapt:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: SUGGESTION: Here are two approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24317764/421195. or  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33949979/421195.  See also setPadding() in the spinner adapter:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33340530/421195.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML file where you have declared the `<Spinner>...</Spinner>` element try to add this attribute (to the spinner) :

```js
android:gravity="center"
```